# When I tried to convert the PDF to an image, the resulting image can be different from the original PDF

Tags: imagemagick, imagick, image-manipulation, imagemagick-convert

When I tried to convert the PDF to an image, the resulting image can be different from the original PDF.

[This is my pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iM9Yy.png)

[this is convert pdf to image output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFwKf.jpg)

The resulting image may have a completely different color on the graphics background.

```
this is my code

$outputFolder = $pathToImage;
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->setResolution(300, 300);
$imagick->readImage($pdfPath);
foreach ($imagick as $pageNumber => $page) {
  $page->setImageFormat('png');
  $page->setColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB);
  $page->setImageRenderingIntent(Imagick::RENDERINGINTENT_PERCEPTUAL);
  $outputFilename = $outputFolder . 'output_' . ($pageNumber + 1) . '.png';
  $page->writeImage($outputFilename);
  chmod($outputFilename, 0777);
 }
```

[i am would like expection same background colour or imageSorry, I accidentally made changes again. It is now ready for QA. if convert time, please anyone suggest or different library i am using php5.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCJVL.png)

Comment: You are converting from sRGB in the PNG to linear RGB in your output JPG. You should use colorspace_srgb, not colorspace_rgb.

Comment: ok will check and update to you